# How do I send React Draft Wysiwyg data back to node.js server from reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to build a rich text editor using React Draft Wysiwyg and I am struggling on how to send back the data to node.js server.
Here is my code:

```
 const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
  () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
   );

  const [description, setDescription] = useState(editorState);

  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
 setEditorState(editorState);
 }




 return(
     <Editor  editorState={editorState} />
      onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
  )
```

The function that makes the http call when a button is clicked:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
  e.preventDefault();

    if(file){
    const data = new FormData();
    const filename = Date.now() + file.name;
    data.append("name", filename);
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("username", logUser.userId);
    data.append("role", logUser.role);
    data.append("title", title);
    data.append("description", description);
    data.append("categories", 'Health');

    console.log(data, 'testing data')
    try{
         const response = await axiosPrivate.post('/v1/posts',  data,{ withCredentials: true,
        headers:{authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`}
       
    },)
    window.location.replace("/post/" + response.data._id, );
    }catch(err){
      
    }
    }
    }
```

This actually sends the data back to my node.js server but it came in as (object, object). I need a way to convert this to usable data for my nodejs. I also would like to send image back to the server only when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify() when you send to the server, and when it comes back just JSON.parse() it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. When I used JSON.parse() I got back block objects. How will I use this block objects and display the contents appropriately ?